# How to crop an image by using python-pptx after it inserted into slide?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-pptx

I've already insert an image into pptx by using python-pptx.

My question is: How to CROP (Not adjust ratio) the image after it get inserted. 
Let's say crop the top by 1 inch, and crop the bottom by 2 inchs.

My original code as below. Would like to know how to modify the code based on my code?

```py
from pptx import Presentation 
from pptx.util import Inches

img_paths = ['abc.png']


prs = Presentation() 
prs.slide_width = Inches(15)
prs.slide_height = Inches(9)
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0] 


slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)


left = Inches(0)
top = Inches(1)
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(img, left, top, Inches(15))    


prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Comment: see `.crop_*` methods on `Picture` object in the documentation here: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#picture-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can crop the pictures using the `picture.crop_*` methods. Documentation is found here:

https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#picture-objects

However the crop methods take a percentage of the total image that you want to crop, and you said you want to specify inches. To do so, we have to calculate the percentage to remove. Like so:

```py
from pptx import Presentation 
from pptx.util import Inches

img_paths = ['abc.png']


prs = Presentation() 
prs.slide_width = Inches(15)
prs.slide_height = Inches(9)
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0] 


slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)


left = Inches(0)
top = Inches(1)
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(img, left, top, Inches(15))    

crop_top_in = Inches(1)
crop_bottom_in = Inches(2)

pic.crop_top = crop_top_in / pic.height.inches
pic.crop_bottom = crop_bottom_in / pic.height.inches

prs.save('test.pptx')
```